# Erro ao compilar projeto Angular 5 "is missing from the TypeScript compilation."

Tags: angular, angular-5

quando tento rodar o servidor do angular para testar o projeto apresenta falha na compilação com o seguinte erro:

```
ERROR in ./src/app/shared/objeto/Venda.ts

Module build failed: Error: F:\Xampp\htdocs\www\Angular\fidaliza\src\app\shared\objeto\Venda.ts is missing from the TypeScript compilation. 

Please make sure it is in your tsconfig via the 'files' or 'include' property.
at AngularCompilerPlugin.getCompiledFile (F:\Xampp\htdocs\www\Angular\fidaliza\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\angular_compiler_plugin.js:674:23)
at plugin.done.then (F:\Xampp\htdocs\www\Angular\fidaliza\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\loader.js:467:39)
at <anonymous>
```

tudo estava funcionando normal até eu criar essa classe:

```
export class Venda {
venda_cliente: string;
venda_loja: string;
venda_cupom: number;
venda_produtos: number;
venda_valor: number;
venda_resgate: number;
venda_dtresgate: string;
resgatar: boolean;
}
```

o erro ocorre quando essa linha é executada:

`@Input() venda: Venda = new Venda();`

quando eu comento a linha acima ele executa normal a aplicação, ja tentei fazer os includes dos path no `tsconfig.app` e `tsconfig.spec` mas não resolveu.

`tsconfig.app.json`

```
{
  "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../out-tsc/app",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "module": "es2015",
    "types": []
  },
  "exclude": [
    "test.ts",
    "**/*.spec.ts"
  ]
}
```

`tsconfig.spec.json`

```
{
  "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../out-tsc/spec",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es5",
    "types": [
      "jasmine",
      "node"
    ]
  },
  "files": [
    "test.ts"
  ],
  "include": [
    "**/*.spec.ts",
    "**/*.d.ts"
  ]
}
```

`tsconfig.json`

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2017",
      "dom"
    ]
  }
}
```

`resgatar.component.ts`

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { routerTransition } from '../../../router.animations';
import { ClientesService } from '../../../shared/services   /clientes.service';
import { VendasService } from '../../../shared/services/vendas.service';
import { Cliente } from '../../../shared/objeto/cliente';
import { Venda } from '../../../shared/objeto/Venda';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-resgatar',
  templateUrl: './resgatar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./resgatar.component.scss'],
  animations: [routerTransition()],
})
export class ResgatarComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() venda: Venda = new Venda();
{restante da classe acho que não é util pois só tem funções de botões}
```

> quando eu fiz esse include `"include: ["**/*.d.ts"]` no `tsconfig.app.json`não da erro na compilação, porem a aplicação ela fica apenas carregando e não aparece nenhum erro no console!

Comment: você fez o upgrade do angular 4 para o angular 5? Se sim, tente executar `ng serve --preserve-symlinks` e veja se resolve. Se não resolver, por favor inclua os arquivos `tsconfig.app.json`, `tsconfig.spec.json` e os *imports* do arquivo ts que possui a linha `@Input() venda: Venda = new Venda();`

Comment: @mercador eu fiz como você disse `ng serve --preserve-symlinks` já havia tentado, estou revirando o blog do angular pra tentar corrigir isso sem sucesso, eu iniciei o projeto já coom angular 5 não fiz upgrade, unica coisa que fiz foi atualizar o `@angular/cli` porque deu um bug e achei melhor reinstalar mas acho que não seja isso pq como disse sem a linha ele executa normalmente

Answer (score 5, accepted):

descobri o problema, `import { Venda } from '@app/shared/objeto/Venda';` o **V** maiúsculo, olhando o codigo eu tenho um include de outra `classe`  nesse mesmo componente `import { Cliente } from '../../../shared/objeto/cliente';` percebi que estava em lowcase, então mudei o `import` de `Venda` para `venda`, compilou normal. burrice minha =)

Comment: Use o webstorm e nunca mais terá de se preocupar com esse problema

Comment: eu uso o Visual Code, mas francamente rs vou dar uma olhada nesse, vlw!

Answer (score 2):

Já tentou mudar a linha

```
@Input() venda: Venda = new Venda();  para @Input() venda = new Venda();
```

Mas parece que a lógica ta errada. Porque o `@Input` é um valor que o component tem que receber ou seja valor de entrada. Não me lembro se pode inicializar ele assim!

Ela pode ser inicializada, mas como você ta dizendo que ela é do tipo Venda então tem que ter cuidado como ela é uma propriedade de entrada o que vai vir tem que ser um objeto do tipo venda se não da erro. Tenta tirar o `:Venda` e deixa só venda `= new Venda();`

Comment: eu declaro que `venda` é do tipo `:Venda` (classe) e precisa ser inicializado porque carrego as propriedades na view `[(ngModel)]="venda.venda_cliente"`

Answer (score 0):

Vá ao seu arquivo *tsconfig.json* e adicione a seguinte propriedade dentro da propriedade `"compilerOptions"`:

```
"paths": {
    "@app/*": ["app/*"]
}
```

Após isso, no seu `Component` na linha em que você faz o `import` da classe `Venda` altere para:

```
import { Venda } from '@app/shared/objeto/Venda';
```

Acredito que o seu erro esteja no import, portanto isso deve corrigí-lo.

Comment: eu editei o ´tsconfig.json` depois de `"compileOnSave": false,` eu coloquei essa entrada: `"paths": { "@app/*": ["app/*"]  }` na hora de mudar a linha do `import` para `@app` diz que não conseguiu encontrar o modulo `Venda`,

Comment: Me desculpe amigo, a propriedade paths deve ficar dentro de compilerOptions. Vou atualizar a resposta

Comment: muito obrigado pela dica, mas o problema é no `import` com o nome do arquivo em letra maiúscula, por isso o erro.